# Load modulation in wireless charger

Tags: mosfet, wireless-charging

I was trying to understand the principle behind wireless charging solution. I have ran into obstacle where i am unable to understand how load connected across Rx coil can affect its the amplitude and how it can have impact on frequency of primary coil. Here is the Rx coil block diagram.

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What is the impact on Rx coil amplitude and voltage/current on the primary coil when the load is resistive?
2. What is the impact on Rx coil amplitude and voltage/current on the primary coil when the load is capacitive?

[image]

Edit:

Here is the link: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51013a.pdf

Comment: Please link to where you have read the things you mention. Apart from amplitude being affected, the other things appear to be misunderstood.

Comment: @Andyaka i have added the link

Comment: Which of the 46 pages of the linked document does it say the load affects frequency? Maybe you can copy the specific bit as an image and paste it into your question? Ditto about the capacitive **load** affecting frequency.

Comment: @Andyaka I had misunderstood certain statements as I was referring to multiple documents. There is only amplitude modulation which affects the current on primary coil